# Display PNG image file with AR.js (Augmented Reality)

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I just want to display a PNG file with AR.js (Augmented Reality) on my web browser with a Hiro marker !! But the result is a black box and I don't understand the problem.

Thank you for you help
Benoit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- include A-Frame obviously -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<!-- include ar.js for A-Frame -->
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<a-scene embedded arjs>
    <a-assets>
        <img id="transpImage" src="http://www.icone-png.com/png/13/13081.png">
    </a-assets>
    <a-image width="1" height="1" src="#transpImage"></a-image>
    <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

TLDR - three.js/aframe won't let You load an image from an insecure host.

---

If the image is not on Your server, You probably get a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error, which means Your website isn't able to get a response (or gets rejected) trying to obtain the image using [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). You can read more on this in the a-frame [FAQ](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load), and in the asset management [subpage](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/asset-management-system.html#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors).

Make sure, the image is on Your server, or find an image on a secure website (It's a big simplification but most `https://*` work for me).

A-frame recommends using [github](https://github.com/) as a deployment platform, you could also use [glitch.me](https://glitch.com/)

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5b13ne3q/) is my fiddle, where You can see it's not related to AR.js.

---

Check out the console, You should see:

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://www.icone-png.com/png/13/13081.png” on a secure page[Learn More]  
three.js:30486:3 components:texture:error `$s` could not be fetched (Error code: undefined; Response: undefined)
```

confirming all above about the CORS error.